# How do you disable the loopback device windows 10?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, loopback

I have found this question for Windows 7 many times ([example](http://burntmsv83.forumotion.com/t41-how-to-disable-your-loopback-adapter)), but this does not work on Windows 10, because I don't think the loopback network adapter is exposed in the same location.  At least for me, I don't see a loopback device in my device manager.

Is there somewhere besides device manager that I need to look in order to disable the loopback adapter in Windows 10?

[image]

EDIT: The reason I would like to do this is to simulate a drop in internet connection for testing purposes.  I am a developer programming a distributed application with [Wamp](http://wamp-proto.org/).  I have a Wamp router, and a subscriber.  When a connection goes down, I need to ensure that my design reconnects to the server when the connection comes back up.  However, I'm having trouble testing this scenario without running the router and subscriber on different machines.  Having them both on the same machine would be nice for testing.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to disable the loopback device? AFAIK it doesn't cause any additional security concerns over any other IP stack running on the system and at least on Unix it's used by dozens of processes to connect to one another.

Comment: @mtak It's not security, but actually testing.  I am a developer trying to test disconnect/reconnect scenarios.  Being able to do this on the fly would allow for relatively quick tests.  I can build a server and client locally, then ensure that my design allows for choppy connectivity by disabling/re-enabling the loopback device.  That's my idea anyway.

Comment: you can firewall a port faster than enabling/disabling device, by the way, and it will be like choppy connection. Or use https://github.com/jagt/clumsy

Comment: @strangeqargo That's interesting... could I just firewall all ports for 127.0.0.1?  Would this accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I don't know about windows api for this (i'm more like a linux user) but I bet you can, maybe installing some other firewall. I doubt you need to ban all ports, afterall your app does not use random ports, I guess. Clumsy (linked about) or something like this is much better choice, I guess. You can also use VirtualBox and kill its network through some API calls. Answer to your original question lies here though - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: though if it's not there, It means, I guess,  Windows does not allow deletion of this adapter because it's used internally for some system communication.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looking into it now.  If it works, I'll let you know so you can post the answer and I'll accept it.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Even if you could, this will break just about everything. It is also *nothing* like a Internet or even network outage. Loopback’s internal mechanics differ a lot from regular network connectivity.

Comment: @DanielB Follow up.  To paraphrase my understanding of what you said: disabling the loopback controller is not a good idea because breaking "just about everything" means that even if I successfully test reconnection it's likely that something else on the OS will go horribly wrong?  Are we talking bluescreen?  Further, the connectivity irregularity from disabling the loopback connector will not adequately test the reconnection logic that I have since the this does not mimic a network outage.  Is that right?

Comment: They changed the name of it to [Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b21eaa2-ea78-4d5c-9990-e35118663476/windows-10-loopback?forum=win10itpronetworking).  Read the instructions carefully by `Kate LI` I have personally verified they do indeed work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the answer [given by @Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/1118881/disable-the-loopback-device-windows-10/1122332#comment1597494_1118881) in the comments I think is the correct answer for the title problem.

> They changed the name of it to [Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b21eaa2-ea78-4d5c-9990-e35118663476/windows-10-loopback?forum=win10itpronetworking). Read the instructions carefully by Kate LI. I have personally verified they do indeed work.

However, for my problem this did not work because installing this adapter, and disabling it **did not stop local traffic from routing to localhost**.  Most peculiar in my opinion.

The answer for me was [given by @strangeqargo](https://superuser.com/questions/1118881/disable-the-loopback-device-windows-10#comment1597424_1118881), which was to use [clumsy](https://github.com/jagt/clumsy), which according to the github docs leverages [WinDivert](https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html).  It's most useful, and this is what got the job done for me.  It successfully stopped packets sent from localhost and/or packets sent to localhost.